# App Inventor Creating Lists

Tags: app-inventor

Hi there i can't seem to find a way to add multiple integers to a list like shown below could anyone tell me how?

[image]

i have tried to rearrange the lists using the blue button but i cant get them to go next to each other like that this is what i have so far
http://gyazo.com/def7fab0d9280065d17a7297e4aecbab

Thanks Dan

Answer (score 0):

Make a list as normal then right click and inline them

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your blocks to explain how a list normally looks like and what needs to be done. This can help others with the same problem. Thank you.